# ¿Como enviar carpeta comprimida por correo en net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Esta es una pregunta editada en base a la respuesta ya dada.
Estoy realizando una aplicación para poder descargar una carpeta comprimida(.zip) el cual requiero enviarla por correo electrónico, pero sigo sin poder enviarla.

Aqui esta mi codigo donde convierto los archivos en carpeta comprimida y mando a llamar al método de enviar por correo:

```
            using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var archive = new ZipArchive(outStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {

                    var imageList = await repositorioEvento.ObtenerFotosPorIdEvento(idEvento);

                    foreach (var file in imageList)
                    {
                        var fileInArchive = archive.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + file.Url), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                        using (var entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
                        {
                            using (var fileCompressionStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + file.Url)))
                            {
                                await fileCompressionStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                outStream.Position = 0;

                EnviarCorreo(outStream, correoNombreClaim);
```

Este es mi método para enviar el correo:

```
        public void EnviarCorreo(Stream stream, string correoClaim)
    {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress(Enviarcorreo.FromAddress);
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(correoClaim);
        string fromPass = Enviarcorreo.FromPass;
        string subject = "Este es el asunto";
        string body = "Este es el cuerpo del correo";

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = Enviarcorreo.Host,
            Port = Enviarcorreo.Puerto,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPass)
        };

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
            
        };
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "TFConMarcelo.zip", @"application/zip"));

        try
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
            TempData["mensaje"] = "Se envio correctamente el correo";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["mensajeError"] = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

En esta parte estoy colocando el envio en la parte de `message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "TFConMarcelo.zip", @"application/zip"));`, como me lo dijeron en la respuesta que esta abajo, pero al momento de que llega a la instruccion `smtp.Send(message);`, pasa sin darme ningún error pero no envia nada, cosa que si comento la instrucción `message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "TFConMarcelo.zip", @"application/zip"));` si envia el correo.
Alguien sabe la manera de como pueda enviarla carpeta comprimida o si estoy realizando algo mal? Se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tengas dudas escribes el método en Visual Studio y mira la ayuda, ahí dice claramente que puedes ingresar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El constructor de `Attachment` tiene hasta 6 sobrecargas distintas, yo creo que para tu caso, la última es la que necesitas, donde

- **Stream contentSream**: Cualquier objeto cuya clase termine con "Stream".
- **String? name**: El nombre del archivo
- **String mediaType**: El MIME type, en tu caso "Application/zip"

es decir algo así:

```
using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   //el resto del código
   EnviarCorreo(outStream, string correoClaim);
}
```

Y luego

```
public void EnviarCorreo(Stream stream, string correoClaim)
{
   //etc

   message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "TFConMarcelo.zip", @"application/zip"));
  
   //etc
}
```

Comment: Hola Yussef, oye ya lo configure siguiendo tu ejemplo, pero a la hora que llega a la linea de `smtpClient.Send(mailMessage)` no envia nada, cosa que si enviaba cuando todavía no implementaba la carpeta comprimida. Pero tampoco me da ningún error, que puedo hacer ?